# Subgroup lattice of this cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am being asked to create the subgroup lattice of the cyclic group $Z_{90}$=$\left \langle x \right \rangle$.
I went ahead and found all the factors of 90 and created the diagram below. Is it done correctly? For example should $\left \langle 3 \right \rangle$ be connected with both $\left \langle 6 \right \rangle$ and $\left \langle 9 \right \rangle$? Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: You're missing a few connections, 2 also connects to 6, 3 to 15, 9 to 45, etc.

Comment: Yes, both $\langle 6 \rangle$ and $\langle 9\rangle$ are contained in $\langle 3 \rangle$, so they are connected. In fact, all the ones you _have_ connected should be connected, but you're missing quite a few. $5$ to $10$, for instance. $6$ to $30$ and $15$ to $30$.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you. I fixed it in the new image. Is it supposed to look messy with so many connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new one looks better, and, as far as I can tell, correct. It's also good to see that you've ordered it nicely in levels the way you have with $2, 3, 5$ on the first, $6, 9,10, 15$ on the second and $18, 30, 45$ on the third. Yes, it's supposed to be that many lines, but I think it would've been  slightly less messy if you'd put $3$ between $2$ and $5$.

Comment: Awesome, I will do that. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

By using unique factorization theorem, $90=2\cdot3^2\cdot5$.
I think it would be better if you draw this subgroup lattice using a cube where the 'length' is 2, 'width' is $3^2$ and 'height' is 5 so that each subgroup is connected in a clearer way as shown below:

[image: Subgroup Lattice of $C_90$]

Comment: That does look very neat! Thank you!